# Not able to execute sql query with traverse in Orientdb restapi

Tags: rest, traversal, orientdb

I am new to OrientDB. I am trying to run the query `"traverse * from #11:4 while $depth<=3"` on the REST client ([mentioned here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Traverse.html)). The query gives a valid graph with correct nodes when run on the local orientDB client. But gives the following error while trying to run the REST client.

Query,

```
http://localhost:2480/query/sample/sql/traverse * from #11:4 while $depth<=3
```

Response

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException: Error on parsing query at position #8: Missed FROM
Query: traverse * from
-------------^
```

Can any of you highlight as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you escape # in your http call?

Seems like this problem

```
traverse * from
```

This is the query that arrive to OrientDb so i'm guessing it is a # problem

You can also use POST command instead of GET query so you can put the query in the body

see here

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html#post---command